# Change CSS based on Time.now

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, time

I would like to be able to add a css class called ".unavailable" to a div that holds a record if the record's occurs_on date is in the past.  This is how I'm trying it....(p.s. I'm new to rails)

```
          <% @events.each do |event| %>

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="schedule-item-list  <%= event.occurs_on <= '#{(Time.now).utc.iso8601}' ? unavailable %>">

 <table width="100%">
 <tr><td class="date-block"><span class="badge badge-warning" style="color: #333;">  
  <%= event.status%></span><span class="day">day</span><br>
    date</td>
       <td >
            <div class="title" style="margin-top: 5px;"><%= event.title%> <br>
             <span class="schedule-desc"><%= event.desc%></span></div>
             </td></tr></table>
```

what I'm trying to get is this (for event.occurs_on in the past):

```
<div class="schedule-item-list unavailable">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#past?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-past-3F) method:

```
<div class="schedule-item-list<%= ' unavailable' if event.occurs_on.past? %>">
```